# How to make an NSString path (file name) safe

Tags: cocoa, string, nsstring, filenames

I'm using very tricky fighting methods :) to make a string like `Fi?le*/ Name` safe for using as a file name like `File_Name`. 
I'm sure there is a cocoa way to convert it. And I'm sure the best place to ask is here :)

Thank you!

Comment: Do search for NSScanner. The idea is to strip out invalid characters, or only included alphanumeric characters in the result.

Comment: There is also the handy method stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:.

Comment: stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet only removes characters from the start or end of the string, not from anywhere in the string (and so would be inappropriate here)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you're explicitly running the shell or implicitly running the shell by using a function such as `popen` or `system`, there's no reason to escape anything but the pathname separator.

You may also want to enforce that the filename does not begin with a full stop (which would cause Finder to hide the file) and probably should also enforce that it is not empty and is fewer than `NAME_MAX` characters* long.

*`syslimits.h` says bytes, but if you go through File Manager, it's characters. I'm not sure which is right for Cocoa.

Comment: correct however I would also discourage filenames with a full stop at the end

Answer (score 68):

This will remove all invalid characters anywhere in the filename based on Ismail's invalid character set (I have not verified how complete his set is).

```
- (NSString *)_sanitizeFileNameString:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSCharacterSet* illegalFileNameCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/\\?%*|\"<>"];
    return [[fileName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:illegalFileNameCharacters] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Credit goes to Peter N Lewis for the idea to use componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
[NSString - Convert to pure alphabet only (i.e. remove accents+punctuation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231764/nsstring-convert-to-pure-alphabet-only-i-e-remove-accentspunctuation)

Comment: For Mac OS X 10.5 and later, There’s a `-stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` method.

Comment: The only illegal characters for a filename on OSX are `/` and `:`.

Comment: @keegan3d can you provide a link?

Comment: FYI, as of Yosemite at least, I can use `/` in OS X filenames. `:` is still invalid. Also all the characters in `illegalFileNameCharacters` seem legit in OSX

Comment: `touch '\?%*|"<>:'` works fine on MacOS and Linux, so none of the characters in these answer except `/` are illegal.

Comment: Also check byte-length, can't exceed constant `NAME_MAX`

Answer (score 5):

**Solution in Swift 4**

```
extension String {
    var sanitizedFileName: String {
        return components(separatedBy: .init(charactersIn: "/\:\?%*|\"<>")).joined()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
"https://myurl.com".sanitizedFileName // = httpsmyurl.com
```

Comment: Interesting, I only report that that the \ before ? causes 4 errors in Xcode 9.2.

Comment: @Cue i think this was implemented on 9.0, ymmv. You may need to remove slash or escape it

Answer (score 4):

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourFilePath isDirectory:NO];

if (fileURL) {

    NSError *error;

    fileURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingAliasFileAtURL:fileURL options:(NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI | NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutMounting) error:&error];

}
```

#### Before Transfer:

/Users/XXX/Desktop/~!@#$%^&*()_+`-={}|"<>?[]\;',.:  {}<>:^ .png

#### After Transfer:

file:///Users/johnny/Desktop/~!@%23$%25%5E&*()_+%60-=%7B%7D%7C%22%3C%3E%3F%5B%5D%5C%3B',.:%20%20%7B%7D%3C%3E%5C:%5E%20.png

Answer (score 4):

I iterated on [johnboiles's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939814/555807), converting to Swift, and writing it as an extension:

```
extension String {
    var stringForFilePath: String {
        // characterSet contains all illegal characters on OS X and Windows
        let characterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\"\\/?<>:*|")
        // replace "-" with character of choice
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(characterSet).joinWithSeparator("-")
    }
}
```

Illegal character set referenced from [here](https://kb.acronis.com/content/39790).

Answer (score 2):

And of course there's got to be a swift2 guy with an arbitrary
hate list (stolen from other answers). That guy is me:

```
func sanitizedString(string : String) -> String {
    // put anything you dislike in that set ;-)
    let invalidFsChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "/* <>?%|")
    let components = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(invalidFsChars)
    return components.joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used jhones answer but improved for iOS. because ' causes paths to become invalid. and I removed . too just to avoid wired filetypes being generated.

Now if a file name contains "sam's" becomes it "sams", fixed the problem I was encountering

```
+ (NSString *)_sanitizeFileNameString:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSCharacterSet* illegalFileNameCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/\\?%*|\"<'.>"];
    return [[fileName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:illegalFileNameCharacters] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

According to wikipedia, the most common characters that should be excluded from filenames are:

/\?%*|"<>

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

Given that, and since the invertedSet operation in the alternate solution can be intensive, to me the below is a cleaner approach:

```
NSCharacterSet *invalidFsChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/\\?%*|\"<>"];
NSString *scrubbed = [originalStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:invalidFsChars];
```

This way you can still allow filenames that have dash, etc.

Comment: The problem with using stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet is that it only removes invalid characters from the start and end of the file name.

Comment: The colon ":" is also not a legal character for Windows systems, which could be a problem if you're accessing SMB-mounted filesystems.