# Is a filename valid

Tags: objective-c, path

How can I know if a filename is valid in objective c? I can't find anything in NSString "Working with Paths" tasks and I don't think doing a manual regex is the right way.

Comment: Surely any string is a valid file name - HFS+ uses Unicode

Comment: Even aaa/aaa? that will be considered a directory

Comment: @Mark: I see I can rename a file to it on my mac, but how can I save a file named `aaa/aaa`? it will try to save file named `aaa` in a folder named `aaa`. Even using `stringByAppendingPathComponent` keeps it as-is.

Comment: Which if you have folder aaa will work - so you can't tell just from the string

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281576/how-to-make-an-nsstring-path-file-name-safe

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty difficult to know if a filename is valid.  The best thing to do is try the operation you want to do with it and handle the errors.  For instance, if you want to read a file, open it for reading.  If the file is not valid for doing that, the open will fail.

**Edit**

If you want to limit users to selecting paths in the current directory, you can do this:

```
NSArray* pathComponents = [string pathComponents];

if ([pathComponents count] != 1)
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: I want my users to enter a file name. if they enter something like `../../../../veryDangerusFile` I don't want the program to run loose. I want it to not allow directory changes at all.

Comment: Why not just if ([string rangeOfString:@"/"].location != NSNotFound) { // error }..? The array splitting just to see if a / exists seems redundant.

Comment: @Kalle: I don't like explicitly assuming the path separator is a `/`.  It's better to use the proper file system path manipulation code.

Comment: I guess if you're writing multi platform code that makes sense, yeah. (I'm not.)