# NSXMLParser adds extra characters to every string

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I am creating a simple FeedReader iPhone app where a RSS is feed is parsed using NSXMLParser. The code to parse the RSS is a standard code similar to the one shown [here](http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/sdk-coding-help/2938-displaying-rss-content-table-view.html).

But I noticed that every parsed element has the '\n\t\t' characters at the end.
Ex.

```
link = "http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/exporting-data-to-csv-the-cakephp-way\n\t\t\t";
date = "Fri, 23 Apr 2010 10:02:55 -0500\n\t\t\t";
```

Because of this, I cannot use the link to feed it to NSWebView and it has illegal characters. Even if I use something like

```
NSString *storyURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.selectedURL];
NSString *webURL = [storyURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the url becomes invalid. Ex.

```
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf%0A%09%09%09
```

which obviously gives a 404 error.

Is there any way by which I can get rid of those extra characters at the end of every parsed string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). In your example there's a newline, and then three tabs, probably for indentation. To strip them you can use a couple of methods from `NSString` and `NSArray`.

```
//This breaks the given string apart at the control characters
//This will find all of the control characters in the string
NSArray *brokenStrings = [dirtyString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];
//Now join them back together
NSString *cleanString = [brokenStrings componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

When `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` encounters one of the control characters, it is represented in the array by a blank string.

For some more guidance, a similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231764/nsstring-convert-to-pure-alphabet-only-i-e-remove-accentspunctuation), and this exact problem was discussed [here](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=73), but in a more complicated manner.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But instead of joining the string back I just used the first element of the brokenStrings array.

Comment: That'll work in your example, but if you have a string like 'bananas\n\t in pajamas\n\t\t are walking down the stairs' you'll only get 'bananas' instead of 'bananas in pajamas are walking down the stairs'

Comment: Very true. Do you have a generic solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Joining them back together with `componentsJoinedByString:` like in the example I gave should work.