# How to compare A to Á on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, compare

I need to compare 2 strings, looking at the first letter only.

Is there a method to compare A to Á, and recognize it as A, without the `´`?

Comment: Check out this answer, which has what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231764/nsstring-convert-to-pure-alphabet-only-i-e-remove-accentspunctuation/1233399#1233399

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSString` has a diacritic-insensitive comparison mode which will do what you're after.

```
// should return NSOrderedSame, i.e. identical
[@"Apple" compare:@"Ápple" 
          options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch]
```

If you want it to be case-insensitive as well:

```
// ditto
[@"APPLE" compare:@"Ápple" 
          options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]
```