# NSString - how to go from "ÁlgeBra" to "Algebra"

Tags: iphone, nsstring, compare

Does anyone knows hoe to get a NSString like "ÁlgeBra" to "Algebra", without the accent, and capitalize only the first letter?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSString` has a method called [`capitalizedString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-capitalizedString):

> #### Return Value
>
> A string with the first character from each word in the receiver changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.

```
NSString *str = @"AlgeBra";
NSString *other = [str capitalizedString];

NSLog (@"Old: %@, New: %@", str, other);
```

### Edit:

Just saw that you would like to remove accents as well. You can go through a series of steps:

```
// original string
NSString *str = @"ÁlgeBra";

// convert to a data object, using a lossy conversion to ASCII
NSData *asciiEncoded = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                         allowLossyConversion:YES];

// take the data object and recreate a string using the lossy conversion
NSString *other = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiEncoded
                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// relinquish ownership
[other autorelease];

// create final capitalized string
NSString *final = [other capitalizedString];
```

The documentation for [`dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) explicitly says that the letter ‘Á’ will convert to ‘A’ when converting to ASCII.

Comment: Don't do this. It is wrong -- See Ole Begemann's response below.

Comment: When I try this I get a "?" character instead of the "OE" as expected. I'm testing this on iOS 6. Has anyone had any luck with this technique?

Comment: @TapForms: File a bug at Apple. It works with Æ so there's no reason it shouldn't work with Œ.

Comment: @dreamlax Yes, it must be a bug. I just tested your code with this string: @"Œ Æ ß" and this is the result I got:  "? AE s". The OE is coming out wrong. I may just have to add a special case for OE and file a bug.

Comment: This method worked perfectly for me to convert city names for searching. Gdańsk to Gdansk, Córdoba to Cordoba

Answer (score 56):

[dreamlax has already mentioned the `capitalizedString` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050270/nsstring-how-to-go-from-algebra-to-algebra/5050541#5050541). Instead of doing a lossy conversion to and from `NSData` to remove the accented characters, however, I think it is more elegant to use the `stringByFoldingWithOptions:locale:` method.

```
NSString *accentedString = @"ÁlgeBra";
NSString *unaccentedString = [accentedString stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *capitalizedString = [unaccentedString capitalizedString];
```

Depending on the nature of the strings you want to convert, you might want to set a fixed locale (e.g. English) instead of using the user's current locale. That way, you can be sure to get the same results on every machine.

Comment: *This* is the correct answer. Don't do the silly NSData <-> NSString business that dreamlax suggests.

Comment: The allowLossyConversion technique did handle some scenarios that I couldn't do with NSLocale.
For exmaple if I have the following string: ßÄÆûñ.
When I run the stringByFoldingWithOptions I get: ßAÆun.
When I run the allowLossyConversion I get: sAAEun.

In my case I want the second option. Is there a way to get a similar answer using less of a hack?

Comment: @Alex: It's not a hack, Apple recommend the `allowLossyConversion` approach in their documentation to transform an ellipsis character to three ASCII periods. @thefaj inappropriately named this technique wrong but it is in fact a legitimate approach.

Comment: What would happen if you passed in Japanese, Arabic, Chinese, etc. characters into the allowLossyConversion technique? You certainly don't want to convert them to ASCII strings.

Comment: @TapForms: That depends on the desired result.

Comment: @dreamlax -- You are wrong, and your method is incorrect, hackey, and poor style. Use Ole's method as described above.   --- To the other developers reading this, vote this answer up and dreamlax's down.

Comment: @thefaj: Then why is it on [**Apple's own documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html) as a method of collapsing certain Unicode characters to ASCII?

Comment: Sometimes you _do_ want lossy conversion, like filenames that don't accept Japanese, Chinese, emoji, etc. So it really depends on the desired result as @dreamlax said

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step by step example of how to do it. There's room for improvement, but you get the basic idea......

```
NSString *input = @"ÁlgeBra";
NSString *correctCase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                           [[input substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],
                           [[input substringFromIndex:1] lowercaseString]];

NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[correctCase dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog( @"%@", result );
```