# remove all accents by string

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
surnameField.text = "Fal à èà ò l'opo";    

// remove space and apostrophe
NSString *surnarmeInput = [[surnameField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
```

I would remove also accents.

Result "Falaeaolopo"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// convert to a data object, using a lossy conversion to ASCII
NSData *asciiEncoded = [yourOriginalString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                         allowLossyConversion:YES];

// take the data object and recreate a string using the lossy conversion
NSString *other = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiEncoded
                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// relinquish ownership
[other autorelease];
```

which will remove all the accents..To remove all spaces

```
NSString *yourFinalString = [other stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

First part of removing accent, code copied from dreamlax's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050270/nsstring-how-to-go-from-lgebra-to-algebra) thread..

Comment: Careful, this remove not only accents, remove other characters like the Spanish letter `ñ` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Using dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion: doesn't seem to work for some characters - Đ and đ for example. I use a specific check for these, followed by the ascii encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` method in NSString.

Comment: i think is not applicable method in NSString

Comment: Just convert the NSData to a String with a `initWithData:encoding:` (NSString).