# Is there a way to use NSString stringByFoldingWithOptions to unfold the single French 'œ' character into 'oe'?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsstring, diacritics

For a diacritics-agnostic full text search feature, I use the following code to convert accented characters like `é` or `Ö` into their lowercase non-accented form `e` and `o`

```
[[inputString stringByFoldingWithOptions: 
    NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
    + NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch
    + NSWidthInsensitiveSearch
locale: [NSLocale currentLocale]] lowercaseString];
```

This works. However, I found no way to convert special characters whose base form consists of multiple characters like the French `œ` (as in "sœur") or the German `ß` (as in 'Fluß'). I would like to convert them into `oe` and `ss` respectively. I found no flag for stringByFoldingWithOptions and did not find anything on the web.

**EDIT**

`ß` is actually handled correctly by the above code. It converts to `ss`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString - how to go from "ÁlgeBra" to "Algebra"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050270/nsstring-how-to-go-from-lgebra-to-algebra)

Comment: I'm no expert, but I does `-decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping` do this for you?

Comment: œ doesn't decompose, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @Jack: not really, none of the techniques presented there convert a single character into multiple characters. In fact the code in the final answer is similar to the code in my question.

Comment: @joerick: as Wevah points out, œ is not handled by `-decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping`

Comment: just found out: The code in the question actually handles to `ß` case correctly (converts into `ss`)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I believe it also doesn't work with AE (Æ). I need this to be able to group text under a common A and O section header. But I'm getting separate sections for Æ and Œ. I'd like all words that start with Æ and Œ to fall within the A and O sections respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From worst to best solution.

Solution 1 will work only for æ and ß and fails for everything else (**œ**, **ĳ**, **ﬀ**, **ﬁ**, **ﬂ**, **ﬃ**, **ﬄ**, **ﬅ**, **ﬆ**, ...):

```
NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Solution 2 will work for most ligatures and only fails for **æ**, **œ** and **ĳ**. I've tried *all* possible NSLocale, so it's not the issue here:

```
NSString *result = [inputString stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Solution 3 will work for most ligatures and only fails for **œ**:

```
NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[inputString precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Which means œ will always need to be manually handled. And best solution is to combine either solution 2 or 3 with a manual string replacement.

Solution 2bis:

```
inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"æ" withString:@"ae" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputString length])];
inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"œ" withString:@"oe" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputString length])];
inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ĳ" withString:@"ij" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputString length])];
NSString *result = [inputString stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Solution 3bis:

```
inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Œ" withString:@"OE"];
inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"œ" withString:@"oe"];
NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[inputString precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Knowing I might be missing some replacements with solution 2bis and NSLocale is unpredictable, best solution is **3bis**. And also this last solution allows you to keep case sensitivity if you need.

Comment: I think the best part of this solution is the fact that the user proposing it uses the character in question in their name.

Comment: I think the best part of this answer is that it actually presents a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `CFStringTransform()` and its `kCFStringTransformToLatin` option.  I think that may do what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried `CFStringTransform(string, NULL, kCFStringTransformToLatin, FALSE);` It returns 1, the string remains unchanged however (`sœur`)

Comment: same for `kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks`