# How to separate diphthong sign character into it's corresponding two letters in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

Is there a a way to fold a String like: "Ändrew Gorœnš" into a "Andrew Goroens"?

I have been using `folding(options:locale:)` ([Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413779-folding)) and so far I have been successful for all diacritics **but cannot separate these three diphthongs `Æ` `Œ` and `IJ`**

Is there any good, non-dirty solution to this issue?

Here is the code snippet:

```
let demoString = "Ändrew Gorœnš"
let foldedString = demoString.folding(options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .widthInsensitive, .caseInsensitive], locale: nil)
print(foldedString)
```

Output will be:

> Andrew Gorœns

Comment: Have you tried the other options, like `.literal`?

Comment: Just did. Same output. `.literal` matches character-by-character, but diphthongs are treated as 1 character. Thx anyways

Comment: I thought that could be the case. How about passing a locale? Maybe try passing the US english locale, if they are valid in your locale it might not be bothering to split them.

Comment: Just tried, and same output. By passing `nil` to locale, it means that it will use system's locale. :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080613/is-there-a-way-to-use-nsstring-stringbyfoldingwithoptions-to-unfold-the-single-f (it's in Objective-C but the points being made are very relevant).

Comment: Yes, I have read this, this is something, but I do not know if this guarantees that all possible existing diphthongs are covered like this. I see that this guy combined my solution with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`, and then hardcoded those three characters to be replaced. I can use that solution, but I've asked this if there is a proper API call that will handle that for sure. Thx, anyways