# Strip NSString of all special characters (é, ü, ç, etc)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString - Unicode to ASCII equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591052/nsstring-unicode-to-ascii-equivalent)
>   [remove non ASCII characters from NSString in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361586/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-nsstring-in-objective-c)

What should I do in my code in order to strip an `NSString` of all special characters (é, ü, ç, etc)?

Is there a built-in method for this?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591052/nsstring-unicode-to-ascii-equivalent/2591182#2591182

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10739076/335858

Comment: Would you like to remove the characters, as in `"Põlva"` becomes `"Plva"`, or to replace them with non-accented characters, as in `"Põlva"` becomes `"Polva"`?