# How to remove unicode in Objective-C

Tags: converters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace letters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739076/replace-letters-in-a-string)

I have some texts "anh yêu em"

I want to convert to this text "anh yeu em".

Does anyone know to convert this text "anh yêu em" to "anh yeu em" in the Objective-C?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSString dataUsingEncoding to convert vietnamese unicode character to equivalent ascii character.

For details, pls follow this url [nsstring-unicode-to-ascii-equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591052/nsstring-unicode-to-ascii-equivalent)